# jQuery delete table row by dynamic id

Tags: jquery, delete-row

I have the following code

```
<div>
    <input type="text" maxlength="20" id="nameText"></input>
    <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
</div>
<div>
    <table id="form">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The jQuery part

```
var rowNum = 0;

$('#add').click(function() {
    var name = $('#nameText').val();
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<tr id="row' + rowNum + '">'
            + '<td>' + name 
            + '<button type="button" id="deleteRow' + rowNum + '">Delete</button>'
            + '</td>'
            + '</tr>';

    $(row).insertAfter($("#form > tbody > tr:last"));
    $('#deleteRow' + rowNum).click(function () {
        $('#row' + rowNum).remove();
    });
});
```

This will dynamically add table rows when you click "Add" button, and I want to delete row by id, but it only delete the last row, how can I fix it?

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/sgs603cm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use incremental `id` attributes - they quickly become a pain to maintain.

Instead, use a single common delegated event handler based on a class selector, and use the `this` keyword to refer to the element that raised the event. Try this:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var name = $('#nameText').val();
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<tr id="row' + rowNum + '">'
            + '<td>' + name 
            + '<button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>'
            + '</td>'
            + '</tr>';

    $(row).insertAfter($("#form > tbody > tr:last"));
});

$('#form').on('click', '.delete', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thx, you help me a lot!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Is it possible to delete a row using dynamic Id?

Comment: Yes, but it's a lot of hassle. This is why dynamic ids are a bit of an anti-pattern. Use DOM traversal instead

Answer (score 1):

You need to use,

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^='deleteRow']", function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

You shouldn't bind the click event using loops. Either you assign a class to the elements, or you can use attribute starts with selector.

In your case, you need to use event delegation as well. Because, you are creating the elements dynamically.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgs603cm/3/)**